# re-render component without setting state react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am deleting a record from db, for this I am calling an API. When I received an 
API response of a successful deletion, I need to re-render all the component again like reload does. I tried it with `this.forceUpdate` and `shouldComponentAgain` but no luck.

I also tried with `componentDidUpdate`, it works but it is calling API infinite times. Below is my code how I used `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  let newThis = this;
  getAccounts().then(function(response){
    if(response.status===200){
      newThis.setState({
        Accounts:response.data
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Please tell me the way to re-render like reload do, but without re-loading the whole page.

Comment: If nothing's changing, why do you want to re-render?

Comment: You probably need `state` that holds the records. On successful deletion you remove the record from your state which will trigger a re-render of the components using these records. Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: It would vastly help if we could see some type of code that could reproduce the issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I deleted a account from ui. So there is a change.

Comment: Why are you putting this in `componentDidUpdate()`. This can cause many issues, like infinite re-rendering. Can you please post your entire component?

Comment: When why isn't that leading to a change in state or props?

Comment: @FrankerZ, Yes it is calling my api infinitely.

Comment: @Rajat Show us all relevant code.

Comment: @trixn, I have the accounts[] array, How can i setState array after removing particular thing.

Comment: @Rajat By calling `setState()` as you did it. But actually a deletion should not return an array. It should at best return an id of the deleted record. Please show us **all** the relevant code. We don't know how you render the data and what your endpoint returns. Is your api actually returning 200? Provide all the necessary details.

Comment: Also, please don't become a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire). Your questions should include all relevant code to solve the issue, and time and time again, I see people editing your posts, but there are still obvious grammatical issues in your posts. `i` should be `I` everywhere. Additionally, out of 29 questions asked, only 4 you've marked off as answers. Give back to those who help you!

Answer (score 1):

When using `componentDidUpdate`, you should always have a conditional `setState` which denotes that you need to perform something because the current state or current props is not equal to previous state or props.

`componentDidUpdate` always gets called whenever your component has updated. In your case what is happening is that you are calling `setState` without any condition which updates your component, and `setState` is called again causing an infinite loop in updating the component.

You should have something like this check here:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  let newThis = this;
  if(newThis.props.{some-variable} !== prevProps.{some-variable}) {
    getAccounts().then(function(response){
    if(response.status===200){
      newThis.setState({
        Accounts:response.data
      })
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Adding conditional `setState` is very important here else you will end up in an infinite loop.

As per the official docs as well:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note
>   that it must be wrapped in a condition or you’ll cause an infinite
>   loop. It would also cause an extra re-rendering which, while not
>   visible to the user, can affect the component performance. If you’re
>   trying to “mirror” some state to a prop coming from above, consider
>   using the prop directly instead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But if i had a changed state then why i need to use componentDidUpdate? React automatically re-render the component.

Comment: your changed state is called in `componentDidUpdate` after your API call `getAccounts` is resolved which is why you are going in an infinite. Please have a proper read at the docs to understands the behaviour https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to render the component again, then change the props from the parent. If props change then child component automatically going to render. And by this features, you can also render the selective component.